# My script run only through 1 "if" on 2

Tags: python, if-statement

Here is a description of what I want to do : 
I've 2 csv files. 
I want to search the same thing (lets call it "hugo") in my 2 files at the same time. 
The thing is that it only print one and not the other.

Here is my code :

```
try:
    while True: 
        if pm10pl[j][2] == '"Victor Hugo"':
            victor1 = pm10pl[j]
            print victor1

        if pm25pl[t][2] == '"Victor Hugo"':
            victor2= pm25pl[t]
            print victor2

        j=j+1
        t=t+1
except IndexError:
    pass
```

I've tried different things such as elif instead of if, replace t by j, passing by 2 functions. Each if works perfectly when the other is not here, and when I invert the 2 of them, that's the same that print aka pm25pl.

Can't do anything.

(here is only the part of my code that has interest, opening of file etc works fine, the '""' is normal hugo appeared in my file as "hugo" (with the double quote))

Plus, I can't call victor1 and victor2 outside of the if.

Do you have any idea what's going on ?

Comment: are your files the same length?

Comment: If you loop like this (an infinite loop in a `try`?!), your loop will stop when the shortest file runs out of lines. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: for each csv: look for X, print X

Comment: @bouletta : Nope, the 2 files does not have the same length :/

Comment: @WanderNauta : You're right, but if it could at least show me something that'd be great ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through 2 lists simultaneously using `itertool`'s `zip` function.

```
import itertools

l = []
for victor1, victor2 in itertools.izip_longest(pm10pl, pm25pl):
    if victor1 and victor1[2] == '"Victor Hugo"':
        #print victor1
        if victor2 and victor2[2] == '"Victor Hugo"':
            #print victor2
            l.append((victor1, victor2)) # add the pair to list.

for i in l: # prints all pairs.
    print i
```

Comment: I'll try it after, I've to go now, I came back to you if any problem or if it's good, 
Thanks for answering anyway :)

Comment: It looks like it's working but... It never stop. 
Had to add a break to stop it :)

But, if now I want to record them in a variable like :
smth = [victor1][victor2]
How can I do that ? 
I'm self-learning in python so... sorry if I  have simple question :/

Comment: Never stops? What is the size and type of pm10pl and pm25pl? Is it a list?

Comment: You can use tuple to store it together. `smth = (victor1, victor2)`.

Comment: Yep, the type is list '<type 'list'>'
Size of one is 291 and the other 194.

when I do 'smth = (victor1, victor2)' it only print me the last line. I don't have access to the other line (and each of them are important).

Answer (score 0):

Do one list comprehension for each csv file:

```
[pm10pl[i] for i in range(0,len(pm10pl)) if 'Victor Hugo' in pm10pl[i][2]]
[pm25pl[i] for i in range(0,len(pm25pl)) if 'Victor Hugo' in pm25pl[i][2]]
```

Comment: Here is the error it throw : 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @Hawkydoky Try it this way. Edited

Comment: @Hawkydoky Sorry. I'm having brain farts. Shouldn't say "is in", only "in"